# How to start off with Docusign PHP

Tags: docusignapi

I'm just starting to look at this php test file for Docusign and it makes reference to two autoload.php files at the top that I down see in this repo, Where would I find them please?

https://github.com/docusign/qs-php/blob/master/qs-02-php-send-envelope.php

Answer (score 0):

Scott, this is an older example and we may need to  update the documentation for it. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.
As to your general question of "how to start off with PHP?" I would recommend you check our newer versions after you decide which oauth flow you would prefer.
If you want to use JWT - https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt
If you want to use the code grant - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant
The first one (JWT) is a bit less secure but does not require the end user to log in themselves to DocuSign, while the code grant does require it which makes it more secure. It depends on your needs. You can read about oauth flows here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication

Comment: Good to know. I'm taking baby steps here and wanted just to see if work using the auth token gen example. If this is an old example where would I find a newer super easy test one please?

Comment: Even with these php examples: https://github.com/docusign/qs-php I don't have access to composer on my web hosting. Is there a way to download what this examples needs as a php SDK?

Comment: did you try https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant example?

Comment: I think this requires composer to install the SDK which I can't do. I've been searching for the proper SDK code library that I can download and place on the web server so I can point these examples at

Comment: you don't have to use composer, you can clone the https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client repo and use it directly. This code is provided for your benefit

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain but this is the SDK I've been looking for? I point the examples at this autoload.php file and everything should work?

Comment: Still no luck. I have that php client and the qs-02-php-send-envelope.php test script, temp auth code, require_once('docusign-php-client/autoload.php'); at the top and I get this in the error logs: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DocuSign\\eSign\\ApiClient' not found

Comment: did you do these :
Bind the PHP SDK to your server or place it in a static location.
To bind to your server, edit the init.php file. Add:
require_once('/path/to/docusign-esign-client/autoload.php');
To bind to single pages: In your PHP file that will utilize the PHP SDK, add:
`require_once('/path/to/docusign-esign-client/autoload.php');

Comment: The second one.

Comment: more of a PHP issue at this point, might want to ask this as a PHP question